# Python ctypes: One byte variable

Tags: python, ctypes

With python struct `pack('<B',1)` value is packed correctly `<01>` to one byte but with ctypes I'm not able to get similar result.

Is it possible to get the same result with ctypes?

`c_byte` seems to be 4 bytes `<01000000>`.

Sample code added.

```
class TEST(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("int", c_int),("byte", c_byte)]

test = TEST(2,1)
print test.int
print test.byte

#bytes
print hexlify(buffer(test)[:])
```

Now print are

```
2
1
0200000001000000
```

Bytes should be 0200000001. Is it because of buffer call or should i declare byte alligment somehow?

Comment: Where do you get that output from? `ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_byte(1))` returns 1 for me.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely to be because of the alignment/padding, use the [`_pack_`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.Structure._pack_) setting:

```
class TEST(Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [("int", c_int),("byte", c_byte)]

test = TEST(2,1)    
print hexlify(test)
```

Will print `0200000001`

Comment: You can just check `sizeof(TEST)` instead of making an instance and getting the buffer.

Comment: @eryksun True, wanted to show the difference in content. BTW, it turns out that just `hexlify(test)` works, updating the answer.

Comment: Yes, `hexlify` works without explicitly getting the buffer. In 2.5 `hexlify` uses the "s#" [format](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/arg.html#parsing-arguments-and-building-values): `PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s#:b2a_hex", &argbuf, &arglen)`. In later versions it uses "s*" to get a `Py_buffer`: `PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s*:b2a_hex", &parg)`.